# What type of variable shift operator needs in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, digital-logic

I have an 8-bit signed variable A and a 3-bit value n. I want to shift operator n times in an always statement but it doesn't work and output is x.

```
reg signed [7:0] A = //something;
reg [2:0] n = 3'b//something
always @(A, n) begin
w = 8'b0;
w = A >> n;
```

So what type of variable shift operator needs? and how can i convert n to that type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the arguments is not the problem that you are having. The problem is that the always block is not getting run. The values of `A` and `n` are not changing and so the `always @` is not ever getting run. If this was a real program you wouldn't have a problem since those signals would be driven from somewhere and propagate to this block. In any case, any integral value is fine for `n`, you just need to have it change during the simulation. To see that it was never run you could use a `$display` within the always block and you'll see when it runs.

When I run the following:

```
module test;
  reg signed [7:0] A = 'h17;
  reg [2:0] n = 3'b010;
  reg signed [7:0] w;

  always @(A, n) begin
    w = A >> n;
    $display("%0t: always has been run", $time);
  end

  initial $monitor("%X %d %X", A, n, w);
endmodule
```

Output:

```
17 2 xx
```

If instead I use the following code, then I get the expected response:

```
module test;
  reg signed [7:0] A;
  reg [2:0] n;
  reg signed [7:0] w;

  initial begin
    #10;
    A = 'h17;
    n = 3'b010;
  end

  always @(A, n) begin
    w = A >> n;
    $display("%0t: always has been run", $time);
  end

  initial $monitor("%X %d %X", A, n, w);
endmodule
```

Output:

```
xx x xx
10: always has been run
17 2 05
```

The other option is that if you have a SystemVerilog simulator, then you can just use `always_comb` which unlike the `always @` it will execute without changes on the inputs at time 0.

Answer (score 0):

For shift operator needs an `integer` type.

To convert to integer you can use `int'(n)`

Or you can declare `integer` type signal and assign to it, like

```
reg signed [7:0] A = ;//something;
reg [2:0] n = 3'b;//something
integer n_int;

    always @(A, n) begin
        n_int = n;
        w = 8'b0;
        w = A >> n_int;
```